# Is it okay to say Jumuah Mubarak?

Tags: sharia, sunnah, sunni, jumuah

I have said **Jumuah Mubaraka** to someone and he said don't say that as sahaba did not do that. This got me thinking..

Can someone clarify with me, is it forbidden to say **Jumuah Mubaraka**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in this [fatwa](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=80288) from IslamWeb, it is not known that the quote "*Jomua Mobaraka*" was ever said by the Prophet (PBUH) nor by any of his *sahabah*, so it is a new thing to Islam.

The Prophet (PBUH) is reported to have said that he who creates a thing not in our religion then it is refused, such as in this hadith from *Sunan Ibn Majah*:

> [The Messenger of Allah (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) said: "Whoever
>   innovates something in this matter of ours (i.e. Islam) that is not
>   part of it, will have it rejected."](http://sunnah.com/urn/1250140) (Sahih)
>
> حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو مَرْوَانَ، مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ عُثْمَانَ الْعُثْمَانِيُّ
>   حَدَّثَنَا إِبْرَاهِيمُ بْنُ سَعْدِ بْنِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ بْنِ عَبْدِ
>   الرَّحْمَنِ بْنِ عَوْفٍ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، عَنِ الْقَاسِمِ بْنِ مُحَمَّدٍ،
>   عَنْ عَائِشَةَ، أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ قَالَ ‏
>   "‏ مَنْ أَحْدَثَ فِي أَمْرِنَا هَذَا مَا لَيْسَ مِنْهُ فَهُوَ رَدٌّ
>   ‏"‏ ‏.‏

But if your intention was a *du'a*, it is ok to be said occasionally, just don't make it a habit.  Otherwise, it runs the risk of being seen as a *sunnah* among many people, which is not of our religion.

Comment: Can any one explain me what is explain about above topic at last in the given link??http://islamtreasure.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/saying-jumma-mubarak-proofs/